# Angular load master template when called partial directly

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am building an app with AngularJS and Laravel for API interaction. I have a master template file, say `index.html` with `ng-view` inside it.

URL for customer list view: `http://example.com/#customers` where customers is the partial view url.

Later I switched the app to html5mode, so that I can call it without the `#` part, eg. `http://example.com/customers`.

#### The Problem

It does work if it's called inside the Angular scope, but If I call the URL directly, its just loads the customers list view HTML fragment (without master template and scripts) and breaks the application.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: So your problem is that you cannot use f5 for refresh? Basically it's normal behavior, because your webserver only knows the customer list response for this URL. It is angular that keeps the browser from loading the URL directly. The only thing i can think of is to let laravel determine if it's a ajax request or a normal one and give out different content (e.g. always main page if it's no ajax request).

Comment: @Namoshek Laravel is only used as an API, its decoupled with the front end app. I am not sure how you read the entire question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research I found that most suitable approach would be using `.htaccess` to route into master template. The following will do the work.

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll try to give an answer as it's a bit too long for a comment.

I'm a newbie to AngularJS myself, but as far as I can interprete your description, you're using the same URLs for the features in your frontend app as in your API. The difference is, that your API is served by your web server, but the frontend pages are served by Angular.

So for simplicity, I'll assume that your initial Angular page (`index.html`) is reachable through your main URL (e.g. `www.example.com`). All subdomains of `example.com` are only for API calls. Means if you switch the page within the frontend app, Angular catches this URL state change and serves whatever you requested by doing a background request (AJAX), but that also means you still have your `index.html` present in the browser (with another subview ofc).

By refreshing the page (or calling the URL directly), you're asking the server for a completely different resource. It should be obvious, that `www.example.com` serves something different than `www.example.com/api/random/resource`. Before you don't have the `index.html` loadet in your browser, Angular is not loaded as well and cannot catch URL state changes to prevent the default browser behavior (namely requesting exactly this resource from the server). So from the server point of view, you're not requesting the main page, but an API resource.

So what I would suggest as solution, is quite straight forward. As I already mentioned, I'm new to AngularJS myself, but as far as I know (and could read on the web), Angular works with AJAX calls in background (makes sense, does it?). So you could simply use a middleware in your Laravel application, which decides, if a request is AJAX based or not. This middleware could then, if it is no AJAX call, supply the main page (without changing the actual URL!). In succession, the Angular app would still have the requested URL as state and could serve whatever you actually want it to serve.

I cannot supply you any code, because I don't have the time at the moment, but I think you don't really need all that much and as far as I remember, there is already a middleware handling some AJAX stuff... maybe you have a look into this one. If you find a solution within your code, feel free to share!